# console.log returns NaN where there should be a number. Javascript - webdevelopment

Tags: javascript, button, counter, nan

I'm really new to this, sorry if i don't get all the correct terms.

I'm trying to create a content slider, where when a button is pressed a bunch of images move a certain number of pixels across the screen, to do that (i'm working in small steps) I'm trying to create a simple counter, in the hope that it will be the used later to create the slider.

When pressing the left/right buttons the console returns 'NaN'
Thanks so much for the help! : )

My code is:

```js
   // Slider
var leftSliderMovement = 0;
var rightSliderMovement = 0;

// Slider Button Left 
   function sliderLeft() {
    //  leftSliderMovement = document.getElementById('sliderLeft').style.left;
      console.log('number of left clicks' + leftSliderMovement);
      leftSliderMovement += 1;
      }
   
 //Slider Button Right 

   function sliderRight(){
     // document.getElementById('sliderRight').style.right;
      console.log("number of right clicks "+rightSliderMovement);
      rightSliderMovement += 1;
   }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="sliderLeft" onclick = "sliderLeft()">LEFT</button>
<button type="button" id="sliderRight" onclick="sliderRight()">RIGHT</button>
```

Comment: Your "left" function assigns the `.left` style value to the `leftSliderMovement` variable; the "right" one does not.

Comment: Since your edit, the code appears to work.

Comment: Hi @Pointy, wow, really was not expecting a reply that quick! Ok awesome, thanks for that, It's still causing me issues, i might try and run it in a different browser

Comment: Well you can see for yourself here. Click "Run code snippet" and then click your buttons.

Comment: Still having the same issue in Edge. The console log returns "number of right clicks NaN" and "number of left clicks NaN" respectively. I think i'll have to think a little more about this one, thanks!!

Comment: wow, thank you, i'm a numpty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps

```js
   // Slider
var leftSliderMovement = 0;
var rightSliderMovement = 0;

// Slider Button Left 
   function sliderLeft() {
    
      console.log('number of left clicks ' + leftSliderMovement);
      leftSliderMovement += 1;
      document.getElementById('sliderLeft').style.left = leftSliderMovement;
      }
   
 //Slider Button Right 

   function sliderRight(){
    
      console.log("number of right clicks "+ rightSliderMovement);
      rightSliderMovement += 1;
      document.getElementById('sliderRight').style.right = rightSliderMovement;
   }
```